# Adjust row count for TableView dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a page with 3 TableCells (Image at bottom): The first cell filled with dynamically loaded content from Firebase for the profile image, username, and minutes watched which is populated in my `userModel` array. I am having an issue setting the `numberOfRowsInSection` for the table because the first cell is dynamic.

When I try and count the number of cells, I add 2 because I have two static cells (the merch cell and the log out cell) that I know I need to display. But since `userModel.count` starts off at 0, the app crashes due to row indexing the dynamic content before the userModel.count array is populated:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userModel.count + 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leaderboardCell", for: indexPath) as! LeaderboardCell
            cell.profileImage.image = userModel[indexPath.row].photo
            cell.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profileImage.frame.size.width/2
            cell.userName.text = userModel[indexPath.row].username
            cell.watchTime.text = userModel[indexPath.row].watchTime
            cell.profileLeaderboardContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "merchCell", for: indexPath) as! MerchCell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "logoutCell", for: indexPath) as! LogoutCell
            cell.logoutButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
            return cell
        }
```

The app crashes at:

`cell.profileImage.image = userModel[indexPath.row].photo`

which completely makes sense because there is no index location of 2 before any data is loaded into that model. But my question is how do I prevent such an error with a dynamic array in the first table cell? Thanks!

P.S if I have my row count as just `return userModel.count` the top cell loads perfectly fine with the dynamic content but the other two cells do not load at all (this makes sense because the count inside the array is 0) so indexes 1 and 2 are not displayed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
if userModel.count > indexPath.row {
    cell.profileImage.image = userModel[indexPath.row].photo
} else {
    cell.profileImage.image = nil //or whatever default value
}
```

Or if userModel is an Optional:

```
if let count = userModel?.count, count > indexPath.row {
    cell.profileImage.image = userModel[indexPath.row].photo
} else {
    cell.profileImage.image = nil //or whatever default value
}
```